# Money not received in PayPal MassPay in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, masspay

I'm using PayPal's MassPay feature to send money in sandbox mode. After successful api call I am not getting money transferred to receiver's sandbox account. My API call response is here which says success.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-12-24T05:58:00Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => f6710b338a345
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 95.0
    [BUILD] => 14443165
)
```

The sandbox account's of sender and receiver are also set as bank verified and are of US accounts. Still I am not receiving money in receiver's sandbox account.

Is there anyone who can help me with it?

Comment: Look into the PayPal accounts in question and see what records exist there. E.g., are there records for both accounts, but incomplete? Is there only a record in the sender account? Is there no record at all in the sender account? This should give you information you need to diagnose where you went wrong.

Comment: I do not understand about which records are you talking? There is no record in transactions about fund transfer. Even I tried directly from sandbox to execute masspay and even there it also did not execute

Comment: Then you are not making the calls to PayPal correctly, ie you are not making a succcessful API call if PayPal has no records resulting from that call. There is not enough information in your post for me to help you further, sorry.

Comment: I took help of paypal support and issue got resolved.. Thanks for replying. It was nothing wrong with account but I deleted and recreated account with same email and so it was not displaying transactions. I also got to know from stackoverflow that it might need to get masspay feature enabled for sandbox accounts.